# How to match a binary buffer request body with Nock?

Tags: node.js, testing, buffer, nock

I am new at `Node/TypeScript` and write a simple script to learn the language.
I am using [nock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock) for tests to check my http post requests with `RequestBodyMatcher`. Currently, it's dummy (see below). Now I want to implement the matcher and actually check the request body.

```
const requestBodyMatcher = (body: any) => true; // todo: check the body !!!
nock('http://api.michael.com')
  .post('/myendpoint', requestBodyMatcher)
  .reply(200);
```

My request body is s binary buffer (some zipped data) but my `requestBodyMatcher` function is invoked with `body:string` rather than `body:Buffer` as I checked. Do you have any example of matching a *binary buffer* request body ?

Comment: `instanceof Buffer` (or Buffer.isBuffer if you're real fancy?)

Comment: I did not get it, sorry :( Could you elaborate ?

Comment: Could you show the example of how this request is invoked? It's said in the docs "nock will exact match the stringified request body with the provided buffer", so instanceof checks actually wouldn't work. What's not clear to me is how it's better to match in your particular case.

Comment: Aha, ok. I did not notice that the request body is _strigified_. Thank you.

Comment: Now I have to convert the stringified buffer to binary and then I can probably match it. Not sure how to do it though ... Maybe I will ask a new question about it here.

Comment: Actually you're expected to be able to provide `Buffer` as match too. 'Equal' Buffers (i.e. having the same content) should stringify the same.

Comment: Oh, no ! I wand to provide a function `Buffer => boolean` rather than a `Buffer` to match.

Comment: I wonder how to convert a stringified buffer to binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's said in the comments `RequestBodyMatcher` receives a *stringified* request body, so I has to *unstrigify* it with `Buffer.from` and `hex` encoding:

```
const requestBodyMatcher = (body: any) => {
  const buf = Buffer.from(body, 'hex')
  // check "buf" and return a boolean result
};
```